# Как связать checkbox и select

Tags: html, вёрстка, форма

Есть элемент `select`, рядом с ним стоит чекбокс (`<input type='checkbox'>`) select по умолчанию находится в состоянии `disabled`, мне надо что бы при нажатии на чекбокс состояние `select` менялось на нормальное (т.е атрибут `disabled` прекращал свою работу, если можно так сказать) Возможно ли это сделать **без применения** *JavaScript*? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

можно так исхитриться, добавить стили, присущие типу `disabled` в CSS и всё.

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  order: 2;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+select {
  pointer-events: all;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+select {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox">

    <select tabindex="-1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `outline: none;` придется добавить, а то на *tab* реагирует.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, ну тут спорно, `outline` лишь не даст "зрящему" пользователю понять, что можно через пробел зайти, а вот скринридер вполне зайдет без проблем и даст понять, что можно тыкнуть, можно `tabindex` поставить, но тогда это запретит заход через `tab`, поэтому тут вообще лучше через JS делать)